# Preventing default event in AngularJS doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form class="form-login" name="loginForm" novalidate ng-submit="login()">
    <fieldset>
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <input type="text" required class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username" ng-model="username" name="username" tabindex="1" xs-input-sync>
        <input type="password" required class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password" name="password" tabindex="2" xs-input-sync>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and here's the controller method called when submitting the form:

```
$scope.login = function() {
        $http.post($scope.serviceUrls.getAuthenticationUrl($scope.username), {
            "password": $scope.password
        }).success(function(data, status, headers) {


        }).error(function(data, status) {

        });
        return false;
    }
```

Everything works fine up to this point. But since the browser only shows the native "Remember Password" dialog only if you have the `action="/"` attribute set on the form, I've also added it on my form.

After adding the `action="/"` the form gets submitted when hitting the Enter key or the Login button no matter what I try. I've also tried to add the `$event` parameter to the html `login` function call, and then do `$event.preventDefault();` but still no go.

The same thing happens on urls like:

```
<a class="xs-btn edit-btn" ng-click="toggleEditMode($event)"></a>
```

I've tried: `$event.preventDefault();`, `return false;`, adding `href=""`, `href="#"`. But none of the work and I always get redirected to the root of the site. The only one that works is `href="javascript:void(0);"`.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong? It seems like something is wrong app wide.

Comment: Can you post a small, simple example to Plunker? You mentioned 'a' not working either for you, so here's an example demonstrating that: http://plnkr.co/edit/9ZhXUtewqNwq31JSdQfT?p=preview

Comment: I will try to find something reproducible there and create a plunker out of it. I'm not able to copy the whole project here :) Do you think  it has something to do with backend url rewriting? Just like it says in the docs, I'm rewriting everything to index.html where the AngularJS code runs into.

Comment: Here's a plunk: http://plnkr.co/PhO4uL. It seems it only works when the url has "http://" inside. Else you get redirected to a page.

Comment: Hmm...I'm just not seeing that. I added a logger so you can see. Are you not seeing all the entries log when you click them and then no redirection? http://plnkr.co/edit/ujkPOR?p=preview

Comment: I've added a console.log to the Dashboard controller. You can see that the Dashboard controller is called several times if you click on the third and fourth links.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. You just have to stop the event from propagating: http://plnkr.co/edit/ujkPOR?p=preview.

Comment: Well, that's one thing I didn't try. Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see, just adding `onsubmit="return false"` to `<form>` do the job: http://plnkr.co/edit/a7bUU1VWAZOUYyXQjvF3?p=preview

Comment: Good point. But in the AngularJS documentation it says the event is prevented by default. What's the issue then?